# server-side javascript array key access

Tags: ssjs

If I got this SSJS object, How can I access key value from "taxes_base" property if I don't know its value?

```
{
   "taxes":{
      "indirect_discount":true,
      "taxes_base":{
         "10":{
            "tax_base":9.82,
            "discount_base":0.8
         },
         "21":{
            "tax_base":52.75,
            "discount_base":3.1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to "loop" "taxes_base" property like (pseudocode)

```
foreach ( $item, $key => $value )
  `do some thing`
endforeach
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great example of JSON variable because if you want to loop over something, ideally it'd be an array (`[]`), not object with properties like what you've shown us.

Read up about [JSON parsing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm) in Apex. You can read it by travelling through the tree similar to how you'd parse an XML document node by node. Or you can create some helper classes that match the structure of the object and automatically cast the variable to this type. There's even a great little tool for automated guess of the structure based on sample data: https://json2apex.herokuapp.com but it seems to produce gibberish for your case:

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class JSON2Apex {
        public Taxes taxes;
    }

    public class Taxes {
        public Boolean indirect_discount;
        public Taxes_base taxes_base;
    }

    public class Taxes_base {
        public 10 10;                        // umm... lol
        public 10 21;
    }

    public class 10 {
        public Double tax_base;
        public Double discount_base;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

So - unless you can fix source format you need to do it manually:

```
String s = '{"taxes":{"indirect_discount":true,"taxes_base":{"10":{"tax_base":9.82,"discount_base":0.8},"21":{"tax_base":52.75,"discount_base":3.1}}}}';
Map<String, Object> root = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
System.debug(root.get('taxes'));

Map<String, Object> taxesBaseNode = (Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) root.get('taxes')).get('taxes_base');
for(String key : taxesBaseNode.keyset()){
    System.debug(key + ' => ' + taxesBaseNode.get(key));

    Map<String, Object> temp = (Map<String, Object>) taxesBaseNode.get(key);
    System.debug(temp.get('discount_base'));
    System.debug(temp.get('tax_base'));
}
```